# Multi level categories in Ruby on Rails and Active Record associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Ineed to create multilevel categories in Ruby on Rails. So I create a model Category which has title and description and has many articles.

```
class Category
  has_many :articles
end
```

Then I need to add `parent_id` field to `Category` model. This field must be either null (if it's a parent category) or has some id (if it's a child category). Obviously, to select any parent category it has to select `Select * from Categories where parent_id=null`.

I hope you understand what I mean.

How can reach it?

**UPDATE**: Thank you for your suggestion. Here is what I have

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  has_many :children,  :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  attr_accessible :description, :title
end
```

As I understood, `:foreign_key => "parent_id"` in `has_many :children` has to be removed, right?

Comment: remove for :foreign_key => "parent_id" in has_many :children,crete scope :parent_category,where('parent_id is null') ,might be this is helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a read of Self-joining models here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins